# Creating a graph with 3 axis in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a graph with x, y and z axis. I have tried the following code which partially works. I am also attaching the plot I got.

What is wrong with my code?

```
mrkall <- read.csv("mrk3d.csv", header=T)

install.packages("scatterplot3d") 
library(scatterplot3d)

View(mrkall)

mrk3d<- scatterplot3d(c(mrkall$rtime, 0, 0, 0), c(0, mrkall$Discharge, 0, 0), c(0, 0, mrkall$jday, 0), xlim=c(0, 23), ylim=c(0, 400), zlim=c(0, 500), type="l", xlab="daily hours", ylab="Julain day", zlab="Discharge", box=FALSE)

mrk3dpoints<- mrk3d$points3d(c("mrkall$rtime,0,0"), c(0,"mrkall$Discharge",0), c(0,0,"mrkall$jday"))
```

> ` Error in xyz.coords(x, y, z) : 'x', 'y' and 'z' lengths differ

[Graph that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yX3P.png)

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong: `c("mrkall$rtime,0,0")`  ... as do the other quoted expressions. Take out all the quotes. If they are quoted, they won't get evaluated.

```
mrk3dpoints<- mrk3d$points3d(c(mrkall$rtime, 0, 0), 
                             c(0, mrkall$Discharge, 0),
                             c(0, 0, mrkall$jday) )
```